# Is there a faster way to build a class in visual studio other than just typing out all the properties?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, class, properties

I'm creating a class in vb.net/asp.net and I'm able to do it somewhat quickly by typing `property` then hitting the shift key to fill out the rest of the code; however, if I have like 50-ish properties it might take awhile.  Is there another way this is done by reading my database or something?  I've seen others use a `DataTable` from a `DataSet` file but not sure if this is good practice or not.

Comment: You could use a ORM that will map objects from your DB tables as well as the CRUD methods automagically.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the recent versions of .net, you just have to type:
    Public Property test As String

and you're done.  No need to fill out the rest unless you need something special. Quicker than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the DB-first approach of Entity Framework.

Have a look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx